# How to access php file from the url

Tags: php, url, pagination

How do I access a php file from the url of my browser something like this

```
wwww.php.com/index.php?page=1&id=2
```

I want to understand how the setting the page on the url works if you know what I mean.

Comment: paste the URL into a browser and press enter?

Comment: How to access the file, or how to retrieve the parameters from the URL?

Comment: Please elaborate your question - what is it exactly you want?

Comment: If I understand, you want to see the PHP code behind the page. That's not possible.

Comment: am sorry please i do not know how to explain it for example i have a page with paginations page1, page 2 which are loaded from the database how do i do the wwww.php.com/index.php?page=1&id=2  please you will understand better.

Comment: Are you asking how to display page 1 of your results for id 2?  Otherwise, I'm not certain what you are asking.

Comment: CM Kanode please that is what i mean..

Comment: You will need to give code.  A good starting point would be to add your code where you are querying the database.  As an aside, have you done some PHP tutorials on querying databases and displaying the data?  If not, I would recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse url in php to get result. 
see below

```
<?php
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';

// Prior to 5.4.7 this would show the path as "//www.example.com/path"
var_dump(parse_url($url));
?>
```

result :

```
array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant. PHP is server-side. You can only see the result. To view the code you need access to the server.